# Upload file to S3 - Got error message I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I wanted to upload 2 files to my S3 from Glue, The first file was successfully uploaded to s3 but not the second one, Here's the code snippet :

```
def backup_report(filename):
    with io.BytesIO() as output:
        with pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        # -------  insert metrics that x need calculation -------
            op_AdReq_fnl.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='weekly', index=True, startcol=0, startrow=2, header=True)
            op_dirt_imps.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='weekly', index=True, startcol=0, startrow=8, header=False)
            op_prog_imps.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='weekly', index=True, startcol=0, startrow=12, header=False)
            op_hse_imps.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='weekly', index=True, startcol=0, startrow=16, header=False)
            op_FillRt_fnl.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='weekly', index=True, startcol=0, startrow=29, header=False)
            op_dirt_rvn.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='weekly', index=True, startcol=0, startrow=57, header=False)
            op_prog_rvn.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='weekly', index=True, startcol=0, startrow=61, header=False)
    
            workbook  = writer.book
            worksheet = writer.sheets['weekly']

     writer.save()
     output.seek(0)
     
     #Upload files
     s3.upload_fileobj(output, args['bucket_name'] , args['key_name'] + 'file1_{0}_{1}.xlsx'.format(rpt_name_start, rpt_name_end))

     s3.upload_fileobj(output, args['bucket_name'] , args['key_name'] + 'file1_backup.xlsx')

     writer.close()
```

Is there a way where I can achieve this ? Thanks!

Comment: You are calling `writer.save()` and `output.seek(0)` on a closed file.

Comment: Sorry , mind explaining it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Try to indent the `writer.save()` and operations after. python will close the file automatically after the operations, hence wrong indentation means they have actually closed the file, and you are trying to perform `writer.save()` again after on a closed file